Decode Safe transaction data with web3py
The transaction from Safe multisig is executing a contract so it cannot be decoded it directly with the contract ABI. The Safe transaction includes data field with long hex string starting 0x6a761202 which is the actual contract call. I can identify the fields via 4byte.directory but I don't find a way to decode this string using web3.py contract.decode_function_input() or any other way.
Any tips on how to decode the data payload from Safe transaction using python?

Can you share the transaction hash ?

@SYEDASADKAZMI For example following tx which is calling updateSplit function with some data. https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc159a1953ad0afd4144bd86b9d3f28910f0bcddb1e6ba392d777489891abf63b
Decoding it on etherscan reveals what address it interacts it but the data field is only hex string. In Safe UI I can read this but I would like to be able to decode this also with python, basically getting the same data as I can see in Safe UI based on the tx hash

You can decode that using the ABI of the updateSplit() function, creating the contract instance using that ABI and then calling the decode_function_input() by passing the hex_data as argument to it.
Here's the code for the same:
from web3 import Web3

infura_url = "https://ethereum-rpc.publicnode.com"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

updateSplit_abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [
            {"internalType": "address", "name": "split", "type": "address"},
            {"internalType": "address[]", "name": "accounts", "type": "address[]"},
            {
                "internalType": "uint32[]",
                "name": "percentAllocations",
                "type": "uint32[]",
            },
            {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "distributorFee", "type": "uint32"},
        ],
        "name": "updateSplit",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function",
    }
]

# hex data
hex_data = "0xecef0ace00000000000000000000000084af3d5824f0390b9510440b6abb5cc02bb68ea100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001580000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a70000000000000000000000000000006916a87b82333f4245046623b23794c65c000000000000000000000000004f67dabb603aaa58ed52641ccaff09c559704a00000000000000000000000000a2d2d22f456125d64beda5a6f37273a13d9de000000000000000000000000000cdd7fc085c86d000c0d54b3ca6fe83a8a806e5000000000000000000000000012ce20df50768c8ddcd5ecc1e9dcbb3cc7be7fc000000000000000000000000046fb65722e7b2455012bfebf6177f1d2e9738d900000000000000000000000005618d6effe2e522f07b1db692d47a68bfd6ffea0000000000000000000000000760e844e6f368ce73f1eeb917d37db19375de3b0000000000000000000000000906eb682c6d12edbe5e0a43e60068e1a7f8bea30000000000000000000000000ad5d1f88a6c27f1ea4e3f45be0f4751bafc26c50000000000000000000000000cefe7d96642a6a9e2c7e34ec1e431e4206d3a9300000000000000000000000010ab73aa48d686b7fd9ec9d50418a14dd23f663100000000000000000000000010c8597a5063a1648ffe13f54e996ba9bb3217b500000000000000000000000014b44b350d3ae3147937cc7689404e00dbc1dddf000000000000000000000000153affb96fcb60085ee307996bdd2df0183a3682000000000000000000000000163fe78004b617045474680ec0d8bf4c0d44ee670000000000000000000000001de6938d9f9ebd43d0cc56f0cef1657d954c9a940000000000000000000000001faa4e309ea6dece1acc4d0e5fe432e2c1148ec2000000000000000000000000200ce476481a89ab7ff9b737393297ae08ce539b000000000000000000000000232e6c4eb0882fcf92865dc1de98bce2a56b655300000000000000000000000024113ffb07189d1e6e169025a424b58c2952297200000000000000000000000027f672013538c9bbbe87eebe6335302f68684def0000000000000000000000002952c5774fccc6935fe0f44ed57c0e7b4ed94972000000000000000000000000299cb850bd75c07ef89978bdc52e062cc4fa02500000000000000000000000002bf7b04f143602692bbdc3ecbea68c2c65278eee0000000000000000000000002d87c6679968a3a15b9b984a5d2c2ece4b9cc7dc0000000000000000000000002f38617c9d8fc5863c5b3de855d76cfb0b7ab6760000000000000000000000002fb858991668840ce34f331402e0b3c66db078af00000000000000000000000031e4b877b9033fcc355af129fcd387031007bbf00000000000000000000000003210287ddee6ece40d17a1f39799239b972a81f20000000000000000000000003212974a4e53e5238f6ea193b36412db9ad61c2600000000000000000000000032323265d9f3df331ccacf7bd11135af14776b690000000000000000000000003b16821a5dbbff86e4a88ea0621ec6be016cd79a0000000000000000000000003b864e8588eb3c1c84169aed272dae21734b93ca0000000000000000000000003d5d2ac4fecf16bb1651a445d5b17f977a8235460000000000000000000000003d84a438af72f6396785eea97b32f903520e36c80000000000000000000000003d981e55bf4b8be8e0d6545e6ba6a140c2ab206a0000000000000000000000003ed7bf997b7a91e9e8ab9ee2f7ce983bd37d63920000000000000000000000003ed9d598b2099d99e9e49b1697729027c67926d200000000000000000000000041fb20055464819f075025d77ddeb0151f85e248000000000000000000000000456287fcc918525d664bb4f62c084be4e85d019b00000000000000000000000046cd90445349e64f895c403c23839e79eb4065e40000000000000000000000004843752dc23f6c28437979770ca710d0e13426e600000000000000000000000048b76905b18c7c80e895bda18061a0e6842794f6000000000000000000000000497f0d190c513f51eac234628200a5e62271a7a500000000000000000000000049aa00072a7ba8a5639c43fe9f6536820e6f5d570000000000000000000000004bfa4639cc1f4554122abb930aa897cdae90d13b0000000000000000000000004d5083dd10f2a46f26f5583c6679f9f8d30ae85000000000000000000000000050122a5509f628e901f9c0238f0168833753239b00000000000000000000000050b6a164ca5673bc6c5bf5e6d9f31587180bf8e700000000000000000000000050d5e44700c10873875b4e75c4c9396562d83be1000000000000000000000000530eca5d32c1bf2865327df76f6dbc73dea1af5c000000000000000000000000552d4145a79ec49ad73cf4aa413d0ebdf7fd0c96000000000000000000000000554dcbaf9d1df74c195490d64e37ec0fdfed3c900000000000000000000000005684435fea165b1cdcbdfbdc39287f7929c6c055000000000000000000000000579fc2cd54b0ca848b180bbc8acf45c54982eec50000000000000000000000005869c17c8934ce9f674e88c7d4f8f94dce193fcb0000000000000000000000005973d1af5c13168bdc85c6e78309272815995ffb0000000000000000000000005abade91ed4b6d11b666280cacb3e4a32898f39b0000000000000000000000005ac41b7e73680a3e77b941fee0bad04f59c9bb7d0000000000000000000000005baf47751b4eee90d7f9fd5eb75c3ad4162421e40000000000000000000000005e1de79fc192618bbc85e62274b12ad0b48f6b3b0000000000000000000000005e5ef2c688e6ce34a1d4b4771780716fe06848fa00000000000000000000000062cc987e62b3bef0ed47ff0dfa8864e7f9aeb656000000000000000000000000642373c947d2c2bed12cde6d5da3dab11d6323f1000000000000000000000000644177f8d79117c2b9c7596527642b3c2d05888e0000000000000000000000006591e7d655f248f6930195385c36b8d5af679b8b000000000000000000000000661b81d462d80786c442774f452464a8c627a20e00000000000000000000000066ee965ffc43d985633d04a044b47b7ba8952ee10000000000000000000000006a5ec9d4a8e5bbb0f7fd04658e088b4c636d7f150000000000000000000000006b29132ea388a308578c1d3be068d0e4fc9915a20000000000000000000000006e22a5e30088c8389dc725bbead5f0675334299f0000000000000000000000006ffd2248ab7e80ef51d7eb4cb60964c83012556700000000000000000000000070f2fe4ab62924db22cc767e32eab599dbecbf9500000000000000000000000071c15691e243be88220957c784053ef0e084440b00000000000000000000000075c7f1f73305bcf9f91222eff570d9c3c423e40500000000000000000000000076097c0e5f2700592aa4132adb5eb59869364bd3000000000000000000000000784b5955fe452c67be9c2f594c73c284f55771e700000000000000000000000078ac9c2545850bedbc076eb30ce7a6f0d74b395e00000000000000000000000078fc08517b0e7fd99f10afff5c3e07049cd00989000000000000000000000000797aba41fd90740a2ca970d6706af05ade09335b000000000000000000000000799681f9b9d7c55ed59f5a0f235cab132cde0a2b00000000000000000000000079a05a48f73c34638b716ad06eff5bcea34250840000000000000000000000007c1c1c2de344dcdd7db65e5d52c5e1ea862c61390000000000000000000000007cc3e83cd74df93fcc879ec7c905635ee6a6c2330000000000000000000000007e59df833869e2997d05e163d6004f3344a052fa00000000000000000000000080bb92f389591d353654ac5580baeff7d0d6e7780000000000000000000000008360470f1793c91c953be453fca52cc63dfcb36700000000000000000000000084f678a3e7ba8fc817c32ff10884d6fb2097611400000000000000000000000086f34d8b98171281ab8bfe65c7e2718e4f002e35000000000000000000000000882337880ee78a7d32a069061994f619fd540f6d0000000000000000000000008894e499d6359f3a7955736794ca9a0d536109be00000000000000000000000088cc2a9882dd3462702e56df1b438fac6e203d4a0000000000000000000000008b49fb41e0df3ea3d01ad9d06501bb5a2257ccb00000000000000000000000008cbf722adfbc071a12aae158a12a68397578017c000000000000000000000000909102b9a0005b92d0091ede42c8016f93151ad20000000000000000000000009192bdc7117a9a0cd989e6363928a26c938fb2300000000000000000000000009258d14db5ae79de3717dfb5f03c3f0a6fc71999000000000000000000000000925f5d6ccdb04f56fba1cdcad92e4ebb0d42141100000000000000000000000092699d64c65c435d4a60e2ceeaeb931db8b1ca090000000000000000000000009598cdbe860a1abd8863cfcdf1cfcd3e609c9ea9000000000000000000000000974b9cb3c122561e3bf6234651e0b82b88fb9015000000000000000000000000975d1040e93316917bd67dd32a02e1929f8af8d3000000000000000000000000980a85ba6c2683e3509752dd3b4eb50165c0e65f0000000000000000000000009915c453cc779109013f1af0c4639277e82572120000000000000000000000009b796f2de75772f1634d78a3ab23a03778d3702a0000000000000000000000009bee5b17eb847744b6a81ee935409739f91c722c0000000000000000000000009e7fa612eb6e771b0e918d94a0d524d6666fa07e0000000000000000000000009f60e4af6020cc6a791b2d1ce9902d25a72ba8240000000000000000000000009fb101bcd5c7baea48e29c45a3f0bd6caaf5709e000000000000000000000000a1506f8dc05b1c22ba23cbfd4625c68599196e91000000000000000000000000a1d76553266fa8ed3d143794a462aafadfc34f74000000000000000000000000a29576f07eaad050aeacbc89ac0518b62fe2f88e000000000000000000000000a3fd150da53b9b6f65ebb8210552da9d56c32bec000000000000000000000000a55f4583b49c8f4a85cc5cdfce503807098509fa000000000000000000000000a87922d0074bcd82ac82816633cce68472548955000000000000000000000000ab8b3647ef7ff66d2f38ee5eaef2b158c4eb52a2000000000000000000000000ab96014a7c078f09418cf899bf197cadff023c16000000000000000000000000ae3bc9d0b8168b0eb27e4ba237fcffc25411c209000000000000000000000000b61384c05086576ebd647c9217ce0765bd748ba1000000000000000000000000b721c2e6640d963e99b37b6437abaf6914a25a5e000000000000000000000000b7a593ec62dc447eef23ea0e0b4d5144ac75abc5000000000000000000000000b7b93e217dd4e6e700e7362cb234d6258438d3b7000000000000000000000000bb3f2f946e8ee2912830e365cf241293636cb057000000000000000000000000bc11295936aa79d594139de1b2e12629414f3bdb000000000000000000000000bc349d1beee33c61f0395d1667e70056b4c869b9000000000000000000000000bedad5f3bb658cc67efdc9e8c17e6a82c1193ef1000000000000000000000000bfbeab0896e29d0db26ad60278d3ab3c482bb199000000000000000000000000c152fd31f285f6c0b3807070280595e7ea713a7f000000000000000000000000c582bf07f73a30dd10cc512e03a50c87383eeb91000000000000000000000000c5a004f720fb103bd6eb5de362115eb4986f635e000000000000000000000000c627a07f25c61244e0c72a2bcf52014015f469ff000000000000000000000000c66efccb88b3b7bde6fc476d8cf139dd38075ad7000000000000000000000000c6ca7c3427ad6b7a06fbed6d18c394e540e31814000000000000000000000000c9187b5c81d63b289811a4fcb9ac7adb7103639e000000000000000000000000cb8dc3bec7b659022ae0d3e9de17322f31e4aa7c000000000000000000000000cf9ebf877688ed88a7479a6e63457fd78d4275ce000000000000000000000000d20beba9efa30fb34af93af5c91c9a4d6854eac4000000000000000000000000d290c3691e8dc2c2e27120259f5e662f309af612000000000000000000000000d31461d449fbfb88dd8d4e7d8fccf79389f671e9000000000000000000000000d4a3030b5f5e8dd4860d370c17e8576ae9951a2d000000000000000000000000d7ecb7fe6d5276773de0a2317de2ff9fde75fad5000000000000000000000000dc871d2c0f92de79e5c1daaedda1372e774f2eb6000000000000000000000000ddeee68ea512b7e1eb62e8b130ea4f67f94d377c000000000000000000000000de09e76d5a06523a85bedada647aa1a78d99d30c000000000000000000000000df6c53df56f3992fc44195518a2d8b16306af9ff000000000000000000000000e019836a41cb707f79b991f60e241918097ac16e000000000000000000000000e05875f287c028901798ac2dc8c22ba908b8ef36000000000000000000000000e1d0a84957b652f36769340c38944f1b97cf3e5e000000000000000000000000e2a296b3d3ad4212b6030442e70419ff7b82fee4000000000000000000000000e9f19b6c72219f9b12c9c367405a90ac9afb2241000000000000000000000000eb2fa209be50fae31948822b6afd62292dd2463f000000000000000000000000eb34bd135afc3054667ca74c9d19fbcd7d05f79f000000000000000000000000eb8e7c90014565eed8126110630efa2d9cd6ebe4000000000000000000000000ed46bffd4b8237a9c7e08f55f0b410544f989813000000000000000000000000ef458c3fbc811912340d23ac5541839c7a7f3b08000000000000000000000000f0443945ad3be9645382fc2537317da97feff3a9000000000000000000000000f1df831ef8dea686508bb27252ea86f72c012181000000000000000000000000f363c519f91e823184061e5bf28263262e2b9b8d000000000000000000000000f51fc4c6ab075482b61f5c1d4e72fadaff8815f3000000000000000000000000f5441a1b900a1d93e4c06cb9c3fdba39f01469f0000000000000000000000000f67c7315391f9712bf04cfb8a72d450f42f9f576000000000000000000000000f71e9c766cdf169edfbe2749490943c1dc6b8a55000000000000000000000000f81a7b58ec5cec5451e21fe73d5af1131b8f785b000000000000000000000000f821ec616fb20b8c53c043afe1122e5d4165a335000000000000000000000000fed50d730c07a85cec48ac586e0372d7d536eef0000000000000000000000000ff9977fb117a22254a8eb6c6ce8d3dd671fa70dc00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d5c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000224e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ce000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015ed00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020920000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001763000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000eae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001deb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017630000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c3700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c3700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021930000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000eae000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000170800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013f20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f02000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000104900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023f5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000181600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011bf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000158b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016ab0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000eae0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001708000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000228c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002342000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015ed0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000eae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018990000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000eae0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d8100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b9d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fc500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025c10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001ab3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000158b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018c400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017630000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f4600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014c2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000104900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000eae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022c900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015bc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000181600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011460000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001049000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000145b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ce000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012a800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a8100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016ab00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014c20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e1a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f460000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e32000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000228c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a61000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000158b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001fcc00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013f2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000114600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fc500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024a40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d5c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001049000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000221000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012a800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001cca000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000158b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001816000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000173600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021d2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000138600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024de00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023f50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c8c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ce000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017bd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012e10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029b800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015ed00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016ab00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018c400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015280000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022c90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ce000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a630000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001cca00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000104900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020d3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017bd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c35000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000114600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d5c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016ab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000246a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001919000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000196d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023f500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019190000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001386000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000145b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000186e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b840000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f8900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000158b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001deb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b260000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ac6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000246a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023ba0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001319000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000284e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b1600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015ed000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011bf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000176300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b02000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000237e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000176300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011bf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000189900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009f9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000104900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001899"

contract = web3.eth.contract(abi=updateSplit_abi)
decoded_input = contract.decode_function_input(hex_data)
# print(decoded_input)

decoded_function = decoded_input[0]
decoded_params = decoded_input[1]

split = decoded_params["split"]
accounts = decoded_params["accounts"]
percentAllocations = decoded_params["percentAllocations"]
distributorFee = decoded_params["distributorFee"]

print("Split:", split)
print("Accounts:", accounts)
print("Percent Allocations:", percentAllocations)
print("DistributorFee:", distributorFee)


Thank you so much for the answer! This is a great help, appreciate it a lot.
So first I need to decode the tx with Safe proxy ABI to get the hex data and decode that again that with ABI of Splits contract.

Exactly, @tmiyc. Feel free to ask if you face any problems further.

Kindly please accept the answer, if it solved your problem. Thanks.
